# How to get user defined data with deviceName and device mac address through Bluetooth device scanning in android

Tags: android, bluetooth

One app is running on two devices. Through this app, two users register on different devices while this data is stored in local. Now App running on any one device scans the second device through Bluetooth while app on the second device is not running.

Now I want to get the data of the app on the second device in the scanning time on the first device through BluetoothAdapter class.

I can get device name as well device address through methods `getName()` and `getAddress()` of BlueToothAdapter class.

How do I attach the data with BlueToothAdapter and how do I get this data from 
BlueToothAdapter on other device?

Answer (score 0):

**Update:**

In the OnCreate:

```
mChatService = new BluetoothChatService(mContext, mHandler);
for (BluetoothDevice device : MainActivity.mBluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices()) {
    mChatService.connect(device, false);
}
```

Later in that file:

```
protected void sendMessage(String s) throws IOException {
   //outputStream.write(s.getBytes());
   if(s.length() != 0) {
       messagesAdapter.add(s);//UI On local device
       messagesAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
       mChatService.write(temp.getBytes());                 
       messageTextbox.setText("");
       Toast.makeText(mContext, "Message sent!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   }
}

private final Handler mHandler = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        //FragmentActivity activity = getActivity();
        switch (msg.what) {
            case Constants.MESSAGE_STATE_CHANGE:
                switch (msg.arg1) {
                    case BluetoothChatService.STATE_CONNECTED:
                        Toast.makeText(mContext, "Connected(1)", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    case BluetoothChatService.STATE_CONNECTING:
                        //setStatus(R.string.title_connecting);
                        Toast.makeText(mContext, "Connecting(1)", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    case BluetoothChatService.STATE_LISTEN:
                    case BluetoothChatService.STATE_NONE:
                        Toast.makeText(mContext, "Not Con(1)", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                }
                break;
            case Constants.MESSAGE_WRITE:
                byte[] writeBuf = (byte[]) msg.obj;
                // construct a string from the buffer
                String writeMessage = new String(writeBuf);
                break;
            case Constants.MESSAGE_READ:
                byte[] readBuf = (byte[]) msg.obj;
                // construct a string from the valid bytes in the buffer
                String readMessage = new String(readBuf, 0, msg.arg1);
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "NEW:" + readMessage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();//------- This is where the message is received
                if(!readMessage.equals("")){
                    messagesAdapter.add(readMessage);
                }
                //mConversationArrayAdapter.add(mConnectedDeviceName + ":  " + readMessage);
                break;
            case Constants.MESSAGE_DEVICE_NAME:
                // save the connected device's name
                //mConnectedDeviceName = msg.getData().getString(Constants.DEVICE_NAME);
                if (null != mContext) {
                    Toast.makeText(mContext, "Connected to "
                            + MainActivity.address, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                break;
            case Constants.MESSAGE_TOAST:
                if (null != mContext) {
                    Toast.makeText(mContext, msg.getData().getString(Constants.TOAST),
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                break;
        }
    }
};
```

I can't say I've tried it in a service but you can try putting the handler in a service. See if it still receives bluetooth messages. I know this works in an activity.

---

Here's an [example](http://developer.android.com/samples/BluetoothChat/index.html) of making a Bluetooth Chat from Google. Has code showing how to find nearby devices, pairing and send messaging between devices.

In this example, there is a [DeviceListActivity](http://developer.android.com/samples/BluetoothChat/src/com.example.android.bluetoothchat/DeviceListActivity.html) that finds the nearby devices:

```
private final BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();

        // When discovery finds a device
        if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
            // Get the BluetoothDevice object from the Intent
            BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
            // If it's already paired, skip it, because it's been listed already
            if (device.getBondState() != BluetoothDevice.BOND_BONDED) {
                mNewDevicesArrayAdapter.add(device.getName() + "\n" + device.getAddress());
            }
            // When discovery is finished, change the Activity title
        } else if (BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED.equals(action)) {
            setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);
            setTitle(R.string.select_device);
            if (mNewDevicesArrayAdapter.getCount() == 0) {
                String noDevices = getResources().getText(R.string.none_found).toString();
                mNewDevicesArrayAdapter.add(noDevices);
            }
        }
    }
};
```

As you can see this line is getting nearby device name and address:

```
mNewDevicesArrayAdapter.add(device.getName() + "\n" + device.getAddress());
```

If you want to run code when the app is not running, look into [unbound services](https://priyankacool10.wordpress.com/2014/04/27/how-to-create-simple-unbound-service-in-android/) and [another example](https://github.com/kweaver00/Android-Samples/tree/master/Location/AlwaysRunningLocation/app/src/main). So in the onDestroy you can start the service and in the onCreate stop the service.

Comment: Thank for this but want to get some other data of user in app with BluetoothAdaper while i have already received  the device name as well as device address